# My Javascript Validation doesn't work on Firefox and Safari but works well on Chrome,UC browser and some others

Tags: javascript, validation, web-applications

I made a webapp for pregnancy gestational age calculation that works ok on Chrome. It however shows Invalid Date for the ${dateString} value and NaN for the ${gestationalAge} value.

```
//DEFINE DATE
const dateValue = document.querySelector('.datepicker');
const message = document.querySelector('.message');


function getDate(e) {
  //INPUT VALUE OF DATE ASSIGNMENT
  const dateV = dateValue.value;

  //CONVERTING DATE INPUT FORMAT INTO DAY,DATE,MONTH & YEAR
  const dateResult = new Date(dateV);

  //USING FORMULA FOR CALCULATING EDD, FIRSTLY SUBTRACT 3 MONTHS
  dateResult.setMonth(dateResult.getMonth() - 3);

  //console.log(dateResult);

  //THEN ADD A YEAR
  dateResult.setFullYear(dateResult.getFullYear() + 1);

  //console.log(dateResult);

  //FINALLY ADD 7 DAYS
  dateResult.setDate(dateResult.getDate() + 7);
  const dateString = dateResult.toDateString();

  if (!(new Date(dateV) >= new Date()) && (dateV !== '')) {
    //CALCULATING GESTATIONAL AGE USING CURRENT DATE AND DATE OF LMP
    const ga = Math.abs(new Date() - new Date(dateV));

    //CONVERTING THE MILLISECONDS FROM ABOVE INTO DAYS
    const gaFu = Math.ceil(ga / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    //CONVERTING THE DAYS INTO WEEKS
    //I DIDN'T SPECIFY DAYS + WEEKS BUT I ASSUME IT'LL HAVE TO DO WITH AN IF STATEMENT UPON THE DECIMALS
    const gaFull = gaFu / 7;

    const gestationalAge = Math.floor(gaFull);

    //OUTPUT THE ANSWER TO RESULT
    message.style.color = 'yellow';
    message.textContent = ` Your expected delivery date is ${dateString} & you are ${gestationalAge} week(s) pregnant`;

    //console.log(dateResult);
  } else if (dateV === '') {
    M.toast({ html: 'Invalid Date!' });
  } else {
    //INCASE OF ERROR
    message.style.color = 'blue';
    message.textContent = `You're from the future are'nt you? `;
  }

  e.preventDefault();
}

//EVENT LISTENER
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', getDate);
```

I apologise if the code isn't readable. I'm relatively new to javascript

Comment: What is the value of `dateValue.value`? Hard to duplicate without knowing that input value...

Comment: The dateValue.value is the first line defined from a datepicker input in the UI. It's the value gotten from the datepicker inputted

Comment: The behavior you are describing is most likely caused by the `new Date(dateV)` not resulting in a good date. In order to figure out why, it's very important to know what the string value of `dateV` actually is. Perhaps it's in a non-standard format, one not recognized by some browsers. Or maybe there is a problem with the locale settings between browsers. Perhaps you could add a `console.log(dateValue.value)` to your code so that you can see what the string values actually look like?

Comment: The console log of dateValue.value AKA dateV is in the format example of "13-04-2020" so i don't know if that should be an unreadable format to firefox and safari. HOWEVER, i ultimatelty convert it using .toDateString() and that is how it is finally displayed in the UI. Thanks for your responses so far

Comment: I console.log 'd the app on firefox and the 'Invalid Date' response seems to be coming after altering the date,month and year as per calculation using setDate,setMonth and setYear together. Could all those calculations be too much for firefox and safari to handle?

Comment: Ah, that's what I thought might be happening. Your issue is caused by the format (dd-mm-yyyy). This is not really a standard date format, and is very dependent on the way the locale of the browser and system are set. That's probably why it's browser dependent. Recommend you configure your date picker to use a more standard date format like `yyyy-mm-dd`, or use a library like `moment` or `date-fns` to handle parsing. See [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) for more details, especially the section on "Date Time String Format"

Comment: Thanks, changing the date format fixed it